# Apache-Ignite XML configuration for kafka-sink connect discovery property

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

I have kafka server and ignite node running on two different instances of AWS. I want to replicate data from kafka topic to ignite. What changes I have to make in igniteCFG? Thank you in advance.

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans
> xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"> <bean id="ignite.cfg"
> class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
>         <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
>         <property name="cacheConfiguration">
>             <list>
>                 <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
>                 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
>                     <property name="name" value="myCacheTarget"/>
>                     <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
>                     <property name="backups" value="1"/>
>                 </bean>
>             </list>
>         </property>
>         <property name="discoverySpi">
>             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
>                 <!-- Initial local port to listen to. -->
>                 <property name="localPort" value="49500"/> <!-- Changing local port range. This is an optional action. -->
>                 <property name="localPortRange" value="20"/> <!-- Setting up IP finder for this cluster -->
>                 <property name="ipFinder">
>                     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
>                         <property name="addresses">
>                             <list>
>                                 <value>127.0.0.1:49500..49520</value>
>                             </list>
>                         </property>
>                     </bean>
>                 </property>
>             </bean>
>         </property>
>         <!--
>         Explicitly configure TCP communication SPI changing local port number
>         for the nodes from the second cluster.
>         -->
>         <property name="communicationSpi">
>             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
>                 <property name="localPort" value="49100"/>
>             </bean>
>         </property>
>     </bean> </beans>
```

Comment: Ignite doesn't need configured to read from Kafka. Your previous question would allow you to configure remote writes

Comment: Note that you could replace that TCP discovery + static ipFinder config with Zookeeper discovery if you did create a cluster